# How to make a button add random numbers from 0-9 into two textfields? | Flash cs6 -as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

There are two textfields and one button on the scene; **txtNumberOne**, **txtNumberTwo** and **btnEnter**.

When I click **btnEnter** I want to add a random number from **0-9** (restricted) into both of the text fields (both will be randomized, not duplicated).

If the numbers are the same, the button will dissapear(hide), and if the numbers are either lower or greater than eachothers, the button will still be there.

Can someone help me with the basic coding of this? I've recently started learning as3, and this is one of my tasks. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

pseudocode, since you're learning and the core of that is to do it yourself:

```
fun roll(click) {
    n1 = int(random(10))
    n2 = int(random(10))
    text1 = string(n1)
    text 2 = string(n2)

    if (n1 == n2)
        hideButtons()
}
```